# Can I keep applications running across X sessions?

Tags: xorg

Let's say I have a Firefox window downloading a big file that will take a lot of time. Now that it's running halfway and I want to switch to another DE (for example from GNOME to KDE), can I do that without interrupting the download?

EDIT: I'm not using GDM or KDM or any desktop manager, which may make the situation more difficult...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to leave the original X server running. You can start another X server on another tty. So, on a typical system, do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>, then log in and run `startx -- :1`. You should end up with another X session on reachable by  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f8</kbd>.

Any number of X servers can be started by changing the number after the colon; if you use a number larger than 12, you can use `chvt` to change to it instead of the key combo.

If you want, you can setup special `.xinitrc` files that start different desktop environments. So you might have a `.xinitrc-kde` that starts a KDE session. In that file, you'd have something like `exec startkde`. And you'd start X like by doing `startx ./.xinitrc-kde -- :1`.

If you plan on running Firefox on both the sessions, there may be some issues. Look into the "no-remote" and "ProfileManager" [command line options for Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments).

Comment: +1 Cool. I see lots of other helpful uses for this.

Answer (score 7):

If you've planned in advance that you want to access one application from several different X sessions, you can run it inside a virtual X server: the application displays inside the virtual X server, and the virtual X server appears as a window inside any number of real X servers.

One possibility for the virtual X server is [**VNC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing). Start the `vncserver` program; this creates a virtual X server and runs `~/.vnc/xstartup`, which typically runs `~/.xinitrc` like [`startx`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/startx.1.html). Then call `xvncviewer` to show a window containing the virtual X server's display. The virtual server keeps running until the session exits or you run `vncserver -kill`; you can connect and disconnect viewers at will. You may need to specify a display number on the command line, e.g. `vncserver :3` and `xvncviewer :3`. VNC sessions can be accessed from different machines if no firewall gets in the way: `xvncviewer somehost:3`. There are multiple implementations of VNC servers and viewers.

Answer (score 5):

You can start a nested X server (Xnest or better Xephyr) and launch another graphic environment in it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. If you use GNOME, click on **System**->**Log Out username**, which will bring this dialogue:

[image]

Clicking on user **Switch User** takes me to a gdm window, which asks me which user I want to switch to. Once you are done with the login, you can always switch back to the original user with either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> or by using the same sequence of commands I stated above.

Comment: Err, forgot to add that I'm not using a desktop manager.